# Salsforce and Plivo integration for making outbound calls

Tags: salesforce, plivo, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I want to integrate salesforce with plivo for making outbound calls from salesforce. I just followed the Plivo api documentation for doing this. But the Plivo api response is showing Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you've added the required authentication information such as Auth_Id and Auth_token of your Plivo account. You can check [this guide](https://www.plivo.com/docs/sdk/server/salesforce#initializing-the-plivorestapi-class) for reference. If you need any further assistance or in case of any other queries, you can reach out to our round the clock [Support team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us).